# Xamarin.Forms Position Hamburger menu behind Android Status Bar or Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Have a simple Xamarin.Forms app I'm working on with a ListView and other goodies using Master Detail for the menu.
[image]

Notice how my hamburger menu covers the blue navbar.
[image]

In another Xamarin.Forms sample app it does not, just works and uses the same code . . . I think, I'm clearly missing something. This app is direct from the [Xamarin Samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/290d8947432fef55852bf381dcaec393d638f150/Navigation/MasterDetailPage).
[image]

Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER: Don't Do It**

Do not hack the Menu to appear behind the Status Bar or Navigation Bar. If you do and any apps that are doing this are going against the [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html) spec as of the writing of this post.